# Automatic plurisubharmonicity for a non-negative function

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

I feel confused about a point in this very short [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs00208-015-1258-0.pdf). On the top of page 3, it is claimed that:

*If $S$ is a totally real submanifold in a compact almost complex manifold $(X,J)$, then any function $\rho\ge 0$ near $S$, vanishing on $S$ (and non-degenerate transversally to $S$), must be strictly $J$-plurisubharmonic in a neighborhood of $S$.*

We say a function $\rho$ is *strictly* $J$-plurisubharmonic if $dd^J \rho >0$, where $d^J \rho = -d\rho \circ J$. For a two-form $\theta$ we write $\theta>0$ if for any $v\neq 0$ we have $\theta(v,Jv)>0$.

The author's explanation is very sketchy and I get confused. It seems that it is sort of standard result but I fail to find any reference. I think experts in MO should know this very well.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give the precise definition of non-degenerate and strictly plurisubharmonic? You are talking about function $\rho$, while give the definition for a form. And at which points should the inequality $\theta(v,Jv)>0$ hold? On $S$ or in a neighborhood of $S$?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Very sorry. I post the question in a hurry and didn't notice that my question is very unclear. Now I have edited the question. However I still do not know the precise meaning of 'non-degenerate' as the author didn't write an explicit definition either. But according to the context, the non-degeneracy should mean (I am not completely sure) $\rho=O(|y|^2)$ where $|y|$ is roughly the distance to $S$.

Comment: you still did not state WHERE $dd^J\rho(x)>0$ should hold. On $S$?

Comment: $\rho$ is defined near $S$ and so $dd^J\rho>0$ in a neighborhood of $S$ not just on $S$.

Comment: Then this is not true. In dimension one, take $S=R$, $\rho(z)=|\Im z|$.

Comment: Yes, but I think the non-degeneracy condition maybe means that at least we have $\rho = O(|\Im z|^2)$

Comment: With this condition this is also not true: take $\rho(z)=f(\Im z)$ where $f$ is a piecewise linear function, $f(t)=O(t^2)$.

Comment: To make sense $dd^J\rho$, maybe we should assume $\rho$ is at least $C^2$ and cannot be just piecewise linear.

Comment: It will not help. With your definition of strictly plusirubharmonic, the statement is wrong

Comment: Really? This is published by *Mathematische Annalen* and should be credible. Maybe we need some additional assumptions? Or, can you further explain why you believe this is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You probably misunderstood what the author says (perhaps the definition of strictly plurisubharmonc). It is easy to make my example above smooth.

Comment: You are right, thank you for clarification. I think maybe I misunderstood the non-degeneracy condition which should really mean the hermitian matrix is positive namely $\rho= |y|^2 + O(|y|^3)$ ($y=\Im z$) up to a change of coordinate. Then in this case I think the statement now should be true, right?

Comment: No, no condition of this sort will make it true. But it is true if you change the definition of "strictly plurisubharmonic" by requiring positivity ONLY ON $S$.

Comment: The definition is just below the only lemma in that paper. And the first sentence in the last page is my statement above. Let me argue as follows. If we just consider the case $S=\mathbb R^n=\{y_k=0\}$ and the standard complex structure $J_0$ then one can compute $dd^{J_0} |y|^2= 2\sum dx_k \wedge dy_k >0$ and $dd^{J_0} O(|y|^3)=O(|y|)$ so near $S$ we will have $dd^J\rho>0$. Where is my mistake?